# Get the initials from a name and limit it to 2 initials

Tags: ios, swift

I have a the following name: `John Fitzgerald Kennedy`.

To get its initials, I created a method:

```
extension String {
    public var first: String {
        return String(self[startIndex])
    }
}

let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
      .reduce("") { $0 + $1.first }
```

The output is : `JFK`

Is there an elegant way with my method (with reduce) to limit those initials to `JK` only, removing then the letter in the middle?

Comment: Note that this will break for many non english names. In  Spanish names the last part of the name does not have to be the most important. And dont let me even start on asian names. If you need correct initials, you need the user to fill them in.

Comment: Yes I was thinking to give the user a way to change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you target iOS 9 and above:

```
let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
if let components = formatter.personNameComponents(from: name) {
     formatter.style = .abbreviated
     return formatter.string(from: components)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thx for letting me know about `PersonNameComponentsFormatter` 

Comment: This is indeed the best way IMO! Important to note though, that according to [Apple’s docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter/1642979-personnamecomponents): *Currently, only names using Latin or CJK scripts are supported.*

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 2.0**

How about this:

```
let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
.reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : $0.first) + $1.first}
```

That will also take care of the case where the name has no middle name or more than 1 middle name.

**Swift 3**

```
let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".components(separatedBy: " ").reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.characters.first!)") + "\($1.characters.first!)" }
```

**Swift 4**

```
let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".components(separatedBy: " ").reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.first!)") + "\($1.first!)" }
```

Comment: Hi I'm getting the error:  'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with a CountableClosedRange<Int>, see the documentation comment for discussion .... In Swift 3+ What version swift is this for?

Comment: I have gotten crashes if I don't protect the $1 code with an empty string check, guess it has to do with order of operations.

Comment: Be aware of exclamation marks! They can cause a crash!

Comment: Double space between the name will produce a crash. For example ```Kunal  Gupta```

Comment: Please see the answers using `PersonNameComponentsFormatter`. This is the right way to do it. The one by cherpak-evgeny is the best one. There is no need for reeinventing a broken wheel

Comment: Works fine.  If there're extra spaces, the force unwrapped will result in a crash.  Need to  remove extra spaces with `.compactMap {
    $0.count == 0 ? nil : $0
}`

Comment: You mus be caution, your function crash with this string:
       
  "John Fitzgerald Kennedy "

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4, little bit of extra work, but using PersonNameComponentsFormatter.**

**// Note:** We Account for name suffix ( Example: III, II, Jr, Sr ) or prefixes ( Mr, Mrs )

```
let fullName = “Mr John Jacob Smith III”

let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()

guard let personNameComponents = formatter.personNameComponents(from: fullName) else {
  return ""
}

return personNameComponents.initials
```

**// Note:** Also create Extension for PersonNameComponents

**// PersonNameComponents+Initials.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension PersonNameComponents {
  var fullName: String {
    return [givenName, middleName, familyName].compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
  }

  var fullNameWithSuffix: String {
    return [givenName, middleName, familyName, nameSuffix].compactMap{ $0 }.joined(separator: " ")
  }

  var initials: String {
    let firstName = givenName?.first ?? Character(" ")
    let lastName = familyName?.first ?? Character(" ")
    return "\(firstName)\(lastName)".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
  }

  // Note: If You need first, middle, last
  /*
  var initials: String {
    let firstName = givenName?.first ?? Character(" ")
    let middleName = middleName?.first ?? Character(" ")
    let lastName = familyName?.first ?? Character(" ")
    return "\(firstName)\(middleName)\(lastName)".trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
  }
  */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is my solution.

**Swift 5**

```
extension String {
    var initials: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: " ")
            .reduce("") {
                ($0.isEmpty ? "" : "\($0.first?.uppercased() ?? "")") +
                ($1.isEmpty ? "" : "\($1.first?.uppercased() ?? "")")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
extension String {
    var initials: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { !$0.isEmpty }.reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.first!)") + "\($1.first!)" }
    }
}
```

This fixes the crashing problem on *Guy Daher*'s solution.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate and filter by odd index

```
let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    .enumerate()
    .filter { (index, _) -> Bool in return index % 2 == 0 }
    .reduce("") { a, i in return a + i.element.first }
```

Note: This one is not care about no middle name or more than one

Comment: What about if the full name has more than 1 middle name, or no middle name? That would not work..