# Swift. Get first name and last initial from a name string

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring, reduce

I simply want to get the first name and first initial of the last name from a name string ie if name is "John Paul Apple" I want the abbvName to be JohnA.

Is there a more elegant way to do this than the following code ... I tried with reduce but couldn't get it to work

```
// get first name & last name initial
let name = "John Paul Apple"
let nameComponents = name.components(separatedBy: " ")
guard let firstname  = nameComponents.first, !firstname.isEmpty else { return }
guard let lastname = nameComponents.last, !lastname.isEmpty else { return }
let startIx = lastname.startIndex
let lastinit = String(lastname.first!)
let abbvName = firstname + lastinit
```

I tried reduce ie but can only get it giving me initials as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285978/get-the-initials-from-a-name-and-limit-it-to-2-initials) post

```
let initials = "John Fitzgerald Kennedy".components(separatedBy: " ").reduce("") { ($0 == "" ? "" : "\($0.first!)") + "\($1.first!)" }
```

Comment: You're making lots of [incorrect assumptions about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) that could very likely lead you to some very frustrating operational burdens when customers interact with your system. I suggest you address these in your initial. design

Comment: This is a much more complex problem then perhaps you expect. I very strongly recommend you delegate a task like this to a tried and true library that has done it correctly. I would recommend you look into employing [PersonNameComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter)

Comment: @Alexander I was going to recommend PersonNameComponentsFormatter as well but for some reason (with Xcode 10), I get "John Paul" as the `givenName` and no `middleName`. Seems like a bug.

Comment: @rmaddy not a bug John Paul it is considered a compound name if you change Paul to something else than typical given names it will be ignored

Comment: I had a look at PersonNameComponents and under the section titled "Short" it says "If a user has enabled the use of short names, the user can choose from one of four variations" ... 
Given Name - Family Initial
Family Name - Given Initial
Given Name Only
Family Name Only 
...although this appears to have the functionality I want, because it's dependant on the user allowing it, i didn't think it would suit what i was trying to do